# Reloading a scene in SpriteKit causes crash

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Every time I try to load a previously loaded scene in SpriteKit, my application crashes.

I am using the following code :

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    for touch : AnyObject in touches {
        let locationF = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if levelsButtonBack.containsPoint(locationF){
            let goToy = inicio(fileNamed: "inicio")
            scene?.view?.presentScene(goToy!, transition: SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.03))
        }            
    }
}
```

The `presentScene()` line causes this crash in my app:

```
2015-12-20 11:53:40.630 Ball[19425:620103] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'Cant add body, already exists in a world', reason: 'Cant add body <SKPhysicsBody> type:<Rectangle> representedObject:[<SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:['nil'] position:{110, 300} scale:{1.00, 1.00} size:{200, 70} anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00], already exists in a world' *** First throw call stack: –
```

How can I fix this error ?

Comment: *"Xcode close my app"*, *"what i need to fix this error"* ??? You mean that your code crashes? In that case it would be helpful to see the actual error message and the stacktrace.

Comment: i only need one code for back to old scene ! do you Know?

Comment: That is not how SO works, we do not just code *for* you. You have to show exactly what you have tried so far, in what way that does not work and what the expected outcome would be

Comment: i tried the code that is up here

Comment: aaaand what happened?

Comment: 2015-12-20 11:53:40.630 Ball[19425:620103] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Cant add body, already exists in a world', reason: 'Cant add body <SKPhysicsBody> type:<Rectangle> representedObject:[<SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:['nil'] position:{110, 300} scale:{1.00, 1.00} size:{200, 70} anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00], already exists in a world'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: whats this , i am beginner please help me

Comment: Please read this article about how to ask for debugging help on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @AndreMiguelCapuanoBrandt You should add a code to show how you create (and use later in code) a physics body attached to that certain node located at position:{110, 300}. But in general, what is happening is that you are trying to add the same physics body to a different node(s) and then add those nodes to the scene which causes the error (because body is already added).

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you plenty: the scene you are attempting to load has objects that already exist in the `SKPhysics` world you have built. The crash occurs when loading the result of `inicio()`, which appears to be making some incorrect assumptions about prior state, and is returning a result that cannot be presented with `presentScene()`.

We need to see the source code for that function before we can say any more. A full stack trace would be courteous, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by removing everything that already has a parent. For example, you can't add 2 instances of a single SKSpriteNode because it already was added to the parent. You would have to remove it. So before the scene is loaded, you would have to make sure the SKPhysicsBody was removed so it can add it again.

Other examples of removing objects to reload a scene when going back to it are: removeAllActions(), removeAllChildren(). Also, to change to another view, I would use the following code.

```
let goToy = inicio(fileNamed: "inicio")
let view = self.view as! SKView
view.presentScene(goToy!, transition: SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.03))
```